# Windows Media Player cannot play MPEG-TS file created in Android.

Tags: android, mpeg2-ts, stagefright

I tested the StageFright record sample (frameworks/base/cmds/stagefright/record) to create a mpeg2 TS file. While it can be played on Android default Media player, it cannot be played in Windows Media Player or MPlayer. Any suggestions?

Note that I modified the original record sample source to create MPEG-TS file instead of MP4 file.

Comment: Is it working with other players such as VLC? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: No. I just want to create ts file compatible with wmp, vlc, mplayer...

Answer (score 0):

Which codec you used to create the mpeg2 TS file. May be difference in the codec used is the problem.

Comment: I used AVC, the codec seems ok, for if I created the mp4 file with the same codec (AVC), it can be played on VLC, WMP etc.

Comment: Android has some problems with .ts files maybe during creating that file there were some problems